# Should I use operation queue for this complete scenario?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I need to perform a scenario with the following steps:

1. To make a network call with some search parameters provided by the user
2. Then, to parse its JSON response and create model entities
3. Then, for each entity created and if it has an associated image URL, to call the corresponding service for downloading such image and to show it in a `UICollectionView` when download finishes.

I need to handle concurrent network calls when downloading the N images I'd need. User should have the possibility to cancel the current search flow and start a new one. In addition, I should take into account that the cell for a certain image has not been displayed yet or it has been dequeued. So, my question is: which would be the best approach for this?

- Perform the first network call (no concurrency) and the JSON response parsing directly using `URLSession` and `URLSessionDownloadTask`, and using `Operation` and `OperationQueue` for the subsequent steps. Use both `invalidateAndCancel()` for the `URLSession` and `cancelAllOperations()` for the `OperationQueue` if the user wants to cancel the current search.
- Perform the complete process using `Operation` and `OperationQueue`.
- Any other and more appropriate approach?

Comment: For subsequent network calls because they have no dependency or priority among them using NSOperationQueue ( whose primary benefit in this case I can think of is dependency and priority) adds no value I believe. You can start multiple data tasks of NSURLSession and later call  invalidateAndCancel on URLSession makes sense. However inorder to download image and showing it in CollectionView I prefer using SDWebImage. It does caching extensively, downloads the image and updates the UI on its own efficiently displays image in collectionView/tableView :D

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to do either a sync or async call to make the first service call. Once completed, parse the json synchronously and then use lazy loading concept (async call) to load if any images are to be downloaded to display the images.

Comment: Sync network call !!! Hmmm thats interesting, which API of NSURLSession makes a synchronous call ??? As far as I know, there is no Synchronous API for network call

Comment: Not the NSURLSession. NSURLSession or URLSession is completely an async service call. You can use NSURLConnection which is outdated. Though I don't see a need for you to do so.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the title of my question was a little confusing... actually my question is about using `URLSession`s or (async) `Operations`s

Comment: URLSession for the service call and Operation queue/URLSession for the images to download.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the network call then make the model objects. return these to your VC through your API completion block.

Then reload your collection view and pass the url to each cell and have each cell worry about itself, use something like SDWebImage to show the images async in the cells..